# initializer element is not constant error in C while assigning address of a variable to the const array

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have this error at `(const)(((unsigned long)(&var)) & (MACRO ))` for the below code.

```
unsigned char var;
#define MACRO (0x00FF0000UL)

const unsigned long arr[4] = 
{
1,
2,
3,
(const)(((unsigned long)(&var)) & (MACRO )) //I want address of var and with MACRO
    
};
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You should look at the spec for a valid initializer.  Performing a bitwise operation on an address won't produce a valid initializer.  You'll need to set it at runtime.

Comment: What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you want the compiler to place `var` at address 0x00FF0000UL?

Answer (score 1):

From C11 6.7.9/4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

From 6.6/7:

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

Your initializer `(const)(((unsigned long)(&var)) & (MACRO ))` does not match any of the above types of constant expression, even though the `&var` part is an address constant.